# Freeing tree, but IDE gains a bit of memory over time

Tags: c, memory, tree, clion

I am using the following free function for my tree:

```
void freeTree(struct node *tree) {

  if (tree == NULL) return;

  freeTree(tree->left);
  freeTree(tree->right);
  free(tree);

}
```

And I am creating a tree/operating on it like this:

```
struct node *root = NULL; 

root = createTree(testNodes);

inOrderPrint(root);

freeTree(root);
```

Definition of node struct:

```
struct node {
  int val;
  int color;
  struct node *parent;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
};
```

I have noticed after running this enough (many hours), memory starts to build up (very little amount) in my IDE (I am using CLion). I am posting to ask if my `freeTree` function is implemented correctly to rule that out and to see if it could be something else causing this slow memory build up.

Comment: What is the definition of `struct node`?  Does it have any other pointer members whose referents might need to be freed?  The fact that there is apparently something in it to print suggests that it might have a string pointer, for example.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Updated question with the struct definition.

Comment: Have you tried using [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)?  Is it available on your platform.  Superficially, your code looks OK, but we can't see any of the allocations, which means you could be doing something unexpected that allocates and doesn't free some piece of memory.  Basically, you need to provide an MCVE ([MCVE]) that demonstrates the problem — then it will be solveable; until then, there's nothing much we can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that your tree is in fact constructed in the manner implied by the names of the members of `struct node`, and that nodes' `left` and `right` pointers are set to `NULL` for nodes that do not have a left or right child, respectively, your `freeTree()` function will free all memory associated with the (sub) tree whose root node its argument points to.  If you have a leak, it is elsewhere.